# When radio button clicked

Tags: iphone, radio-button

In my application I am implementing radio buttons in each row in table view.
The problem is when I am clicking on 1st row's radio button, somewhere i.e, 5th row's radio button was selected.

I need to select the button which I am clicking. here is the code what I did.

Thanks in advance.

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];


        UIImageView *backGroundImageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"History_strip_bg1.png"]];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:backGroundImageView];
        [backGroundImageView release];

        cell.accessoryView=[[ UIImageView alloc ]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow2.png"]];
        if(doneBtnFlag)
        {

            radioBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [radioBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_button_1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [radioBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_button_selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
            [radioBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(2, 17, 25, 25)];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:radioBtn];
            [radioBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(radioButtonClicked:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            radioBtn.tag = 1;

        }


        btn=(UIButton*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
}
    return cell;

}






- (IBAction)radioButtonClicked:(id)sender event : (id)event
{
    btn.selected = YES;

    rightBtn.enabled =YES;
    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:contactsTblView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [contactsTblView indexPathForRowAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];


    NSLog(@"indexPath %@",indexPath);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code has a few problems.

## 1)

You are not handling the case where [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier] is actually returning a valid cell to use, and instead you're only doing work if "cell == NULL".

I bet if you set breakpoints and look at (or NSLog out the value of) indexPath.row, you'll see the code inside the "cell == NULL" case only gets called sporadically.

## 2)

What is "btn" used for?  you assign it and then don't do anything with it.